# position:fixed on my nav bar breaks scrolling

Tags: html, css

I had a request to make our mobile webapps nav bar stay fixed. This should be so simple but as soon as I set position:fixed on the div that wraps it all hell broke loose.

First all other elements are now pushed up and overlap. that I get and can work with. The big issue is that scrolling doesnt work at all now. I can click down on mouse scroll button to get the "drag scroll" but spinning the wheel does nothing in the latest chrome, ie10 and safari. This is a mobile app so they wont be using a mouse most likely but it also makes the scrolling very choppy on a device. tested with iOS and android

interestingly ie interprets the middle button click as a left mouse click.

I found an so question that mentioned fixed wont work if there are transforms. That made fixed actually work as fixed instead of absolute but I still get the above issue.

CSS

```
#header {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  text-align:center;
  height: 40px;
  background: black;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="header">
  <table class="head">
    <tr>
      <td class="hleft" id="logout" onclick="javascript: window.history.back();"></td>
      <td class="comm">Community</td>
      <td><asp:TextBox ID="searchbox" CssClass="k-textbox searchSmall" runat="server" OnTextChanged="searchbox_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

EDIT: I am only using table because I was having trouble getting the center text to truncate properly and be the right length, kept going and was under the next cell, still doing this btw. The tables are not a requirement and I would actually prefer to do the standard styled list menu but I tried that and couldnt get it to behave.

Comment: post your `#wrap` CSS please

Comment: @HC_ there is no #wrap the wrapper I mentioned is the div#header

Comment: What about a Fiddle to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Seems fine to me, it scrolled just fine and over the content.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post the rest of your code, but it seems fine to me. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/t3uxS/

Were you keeping the fixed top bar within the wrapper with the rest of your page content?

**edit**

Add more content (blah blah blah's) to `<div class="content">` to see the scrolling (if you need to).

It's only going to work like this:

```
<div id="header">
</div>
<div class="content">
</div>
```

Comment: I think I am. I will try to break it out and see if that works. I wonder if the form tag is effecting this as this is an ASP.NET project (not MVC) and I might have some styles on that as well.

Answer (score 0):

your code does look correct to me, it does look like you forgot to add a # to your css so instead of header{} it would be #header{} since it is a div id not a header tag

Comment: thanks, but SO must have removed it when I copy pasted and I missed it .

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be related to the other tags on your site.  Setting your heading position to fixed will pull that section out of the normal page flow and the other tag section will fill in the space underand around it.  Could we see the rest of your code and css?